# В шейдерах OpenGL не получается использовать texture2D и textureCube вместе

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Мне надо использовать обычную 2d текстуру и текстуру куба через один шейдер, но если я использую их через if то всё ломается, нет ничего, чёрное окно. Если использовать что-то одно, то всё нормально, например если я использую только textureCube, то куб будет с текстурой, остальное нет.
Погуглил, нашёл такой же открытый вопрос на английском, там был ответ (он не был помечен как правильный), но я его не понял.

```
//fragment shader
#version 120

uniform sampler2D GL_TEXTURE_2D; 
uniform samplerCube GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP;    

varying vec4 color;
uniform int setTexture;

uniform int isCube;

varying vec4 TexCoord;

void isCubes()
{
    gl_FragColor = textureCube(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, TexCoord.rgb);
}

void notCube()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TexCoord.rg);
}

void main()
{    
    if(setTexture != 0)
    {
        if(isCube != 0)
            isCubes();
        else
            notCube();
    }
    else
    {
        gl_FragColor = color;
    }
    if(gl_FragCoord.x > ((1920.0/2.0)-1.0) && gl_FragCoord.x < ((1920.0/2.0)+1.0) && gl_FragCoord.y > ((1080.0/2.0)-1.0)&& gl_FragCoord.y < ((1080.0/2.0)+1.0))
    gl_FragColor.rgb = vec3(1)-gl_FragColor.rgb;
}
```

```
//vertex shader
#version 120

varying vec4 color;
varying vec4 TexCoord;

void main()
{
  
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    
    color = gl_Color;
    
    TexCoord = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
}
```

Comment: Что говорит компилятор шейдера, какие ошибки OpenGL выдает? В RenderDoc проверяли?

Comment: @Kromster, у компилятора шейдера ошибок нет, в RenderDoc не проверял

Comment: @Kromster, RenderDoc, я так полагаю, работает только с OpenGL 3.2, пишет  
Capturing OpenGL.  
Onlv OpenGL 3.2+ contexts are supported.  
Captures disabled.  
Unsupported functions used:  
- glBegin  
- glColor3f  
- glColor4d  
- glColor4f
-...

Comment: Просто судя по коду, если вы говорите, что по отдельности все работает, то не видно причин, почему бы оно не работало вот так (и не выдавало ошибок)

Comment: @Kromster, я тоже не могу понять в чём дело, оно как то странно работает, если я сделаю обычную переменную, у которой значение будет всегда 0 и поставлю на место isCube в if то всё так же не отображается, чёрное окно, но если я сделаю переменную константной, то будто этого ответвления нет, например если значение константы 0, то рисуются все 2D текстуры.

Comment: IF-ы в шейдерах (и любые ветвящиеся логики, типа циклов с неизвестным наперед числом итераций) работают достаточно странно, т.к. "под капотом" видеокарта просчитывает обе ветки и потом один результат отбрасывает (что не всегда получается без побочных эффектов).

Comment: @Kromster, тогда можно как то сделать такой же функционал без if-ов?

Comment: Я заметил, что если использовать обе функции подряд, то всё равно будет окно чёрное

Comment: Например, если я сделаю что-то на вроде 
```gl_FragColor = textureCube(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, TexCoord.rgb);  
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TexCoord.rg);  
    gl_FragColor = color;  
```
то окно всё равно будет чёрным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение было найдено, проблема была из-за того, что я текстуры разного типа загружал в 1 текстурный блок. `glActiveTexture` меняет текстурные блоки. Например, для загрузки 2D текстур можно использовать `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);` а для загрузки кубических `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);`, можно выбрать любой текстурный блок от 0 до 31.
Так же в шейдеры надо передать значение текстурного блока через `glUniform1i`
Например, если программа шейдера называется `prog`, в шейдерах `uniform sampler2D` называется `texture_2D;` и она используется для функции `texture2D`(в новых версиях GL `texture`) то передача значения текстурного блока будет выглядеть так `glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(prog,"texture_2D"),0);` а для кубической текстуры будет так `glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(prog,"cubeTexture"),1);` (`uniform samplerCube` должен быть `cubeTexture;` но может быть любым другим)
Для удобной загрузки текстур в блоки я использую свою функцию

```
void BindTexture(int type, int id)
{

    glUniform1i(SHDsetTexture,id);
    if(type == GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP) 
    {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);//0 потому что у меня не работает 1, можно изменить на 1
        glBindTexture(type,id); 
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(prog,"cubeTexture"),0); //тут должно быть число текстурного блока, если текстурный блок GL_TEXTURE0 то и тут должно быть 0, GL_TEXTURE1 то 1 и т.п.
    }
    else 
    {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);//тут тоже самое что и выше, но блоки не должны совпадать
        glBindTexture(type,id); 
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(prog,"texture_2D"),1);
    }
    
}
```

P.S. Прежде чем ставить -1 рейтинг, пожалуйста, обоснуйте его в коментариях, я обьясню если чего то не понятно.